# If Statement for Hiding Rows

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have a set of rows that needs to be hidden.  I want to attach it to a button so when it is  use it will hide/unhide it depending on the state that it is in.  I was wondering what I wrote wrong in my code because runs however nothing changes in my document.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BBG()

Dim BBG As Range

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        Set BBG = .Rows(12).Range
        BBG.End = .Rows(33).Range.End
    End With

    If BBG.Font.Hidden = False Then
        With BBG.Font
        .Hidden = True
        End With

    ElseIf BBG.Font.Hidden = True Then
        With BBG.Font
        .Hidden = False
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: What specifically isn't working? You are missing an 'End With' block where you do `With BBG.Font`. Beyond this it is unclear what you need.

Comment: Most probably the missing `end with`  in the `if`

Comment: @BrandonBarney so I fixed the 'End With' block.  The code runs but nothing changes in the document.

Comment: @litelite just fixed that part, so the code runs, but nothing changes.

Comment: Try using `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name`. Use of `ActiveDocument` and other various forms of `Active` is highly discouraged in VBA, particularly due to it's bug-prone nature.

Comment: @BrandonBarney nothing happens when I attempt to use 'Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name'.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the `Hidden` property is currently `wdUndefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't give a variable the same name as the Sub. The code below worked perfectly for me.

```
Private Sub SetBBG()

    Dim BBG As Range

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        Set BBG = .Rows(12).Range
        BBG.End = .Rows(33).Range.End
    End With

    With BBG.Font
        .Hidden = (.Hidden + 1) * -1
    End With
    Debug.Print BBG.Font.Hidden
End Sub
```